# "Малообеспечен" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

В предложении "Такой человек, как правило, мало()обеспечен" слово "мало()обеспечен" будет писаться слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 3):

Слитно.

[Правописание сложных слов](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/156-pravopisanieslognyhslov.html)

> **Следующие разряды слов пишутся слитно**
>
> Сложные слова, первая часть которых совпадает с формой числительного (двух-, трёх-, пяти-  и т. п.). а также слова с первыми частями дву-, тре-, много-, **мало-** ...

Comment: Сложные слова, первая часть которых совпадает с формой числительного (двух-, трёх-, пяти-  и т. п.), а также слова с первыми частями дву-, тре-, много-, **мало-, например: малолюдье, малоснежный, малопривлекательный.**

Comment: А при чем тут двух-, трех-? Мало здесь наречие,  а не числительное.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что в данном случае ОБЪЯСНЕНИЕ НЕ ПО ТЕМЕ. Слово "малообеспеченный" образовано сложением наречия и причастия, а вот "малолюдье" - на основе сочетания "мало людей" с подчинительной связью и при использовании суффикса, даже этого хватило бы для объяснения слитного написания (слова "людье" не существует). Здесь мало - неопределенное числительное (мало снега, мало людей), но в "малопривлекательный" - "мало" тоже наречие. В общем, выбран самый экзотический способ обоснования. Не понимаю, почему он Вам нравится.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: Такой человек, как правило, **малообеспечен**. (Беден, другими словами).

Это краткая форма **термина** "малообеспеченный", который можно найти в словаре.

МАЛООБЕСПЕЧЕННЫЙ,  Не обладающий достаточными материальными средствами для безбедного жилья; недостаточно обеспеченный. М-ая семья.

Как и все термины, слово "малообеспеченный" – сочетание неустойчивое: в других ситуациях и под влиянием зависимых слов распадается на исходные составные части (наречие и причастие), например: Почему Урал мало обеспечен водными ресурсами?